# What does 'address an issue' mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I always understood 'address an issue' to mean fix or solve an issue. However, a colleague of mine questioned this today and after doing a web search it seems that the more correct or common meaning of this phrase is 'to bring under discussion'.

What is the accepted meaning/usage of this phrase?

Comment: The whole point of the phrase is that it is wishy-washy weasel wording. You don't promise the problem has been solved, and indeed do not so much as admit there was one.

Comment: It can mean either, depending on the context (and/or the vagueness thereof, or how euphemistically the term is being used -- for instance, if your boss tells you "I think you need to address your appearance", it probably doesn't just mean "Think of some possible improvements to the way you look", it means "I'm politely ordering you to dress more smartly!"). "Address" as used by your colleague means "give attention to".

Comment: ***address* 3** Think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem): *a fundamental problem has still **to be addressed***; *The second half of this book, once the history has been dealt with, **addresses the problems** of the present, issue by issue.*; *A typical day begins with a staff meeting, where any issues and **problems are addressed**.* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/address

Comment: @ErikKowal I can only mean one thing. See the reference above.

Comment: @Kris - You may think that; millions of people think otherwise, including those who apply the verb less narrowly than your dictionary reference does.

Comment: @ErikKowal If so, they are in error.

Comment: @Kris - No, your prescriptivist attitude is in error.

Comment: um, and so language evolves?

Comment: Put on hold as off-topic? How is this off-topic?? I thought the name of this forum was 'English language & USAGE'?

Comment: Style guides consider it a poor use of language (see 'weasel words'). Better to say 'fix (or solve) a problem'. @Kris, your certitude is erroneous, per Erik Kowal, it means many things - in fact so many it's a problem and considered poor use of language by pretty much any style guide on the English language you can find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least [one dictionary (ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/address#address__25) has "Think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem)" which is related to golfing usage:

> **3.** Think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem)
>   *The second half of this book, once the history has been dealt with, addresses the problems of the present, issue by issue.*
>
> **4.** *Golf* Take up one’s stance and prepare to hit (the ball)

You might find a use like

> The bug which caused the application to crash was addressed in Version 4.5.6

where the writer actually means *fixed* — or at least wants to give that impression — as there is no point in reporting that a bug has merely been considered unless it is actually fixed. I would call this a specialised use, a jargon word, as its intended meaning is an extension of "thought about".

Answer (score 2):

To address an issue is to direct attention to it. It doesn't mean the issue will be solved, only acknowledged. In a similar way in golf, when teeing off you address the ball before swinging. That doesn't mean you're actually going to hit it, and if you do it doesn't mean you'll do it very well. One can address an issue or problem, or in other words acknowledge, or focus on it for a long time. That doesn't in and of itself solve the problem. So I think your colleague is correct in saying that addressing an issue is 'to bring under discussion'.